# How can I add spacing between the text and arrows of a Picker?

Tags: swiftui

I have the code below to style a `Picker` like I want (I want spacing between the text and the chevrons, but that's apparently not possible). I added the view like I want it, and then a `Picker` on top to have the functionality. The problem is now that I can only tap on the `Picker` (that's only in the middle of the view) and I cannot tap outside of it to open the options view. How can I add spacing between the text and arrows of the `Picker`?

```
struct CustomPickerView: View {
    var options: [String]
    @Binding var selectedOption: String
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                Text(selectedOption)
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }
            }.padding()
            
            Picker("Select an option", selection: $selectedOption) {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            .accentColor(.clear)
        }
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
        .clipShape(Rectangle())
        .shadow(color: Color(UIColor.label), radius: 1)
    }
}

struct CustomPickerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomPickerView(options: ["Company1", "Company2", "Company3", "Company4"], selectedOption: .constant("Company1"))
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't make a `PickerView` do what you want in this instance. You can, however, accomplish the same thing with a `Menu`:

```
struct CustomPickerView: View {
    var options: [String]
    @Binding var selectedOption: String
    var body: some View {
        Menu {
            ForEach(options, id: \.self) { option in
                Button {
                    selectedOption = option
                } label: {
                    Text(option)
                }
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text(selectedOption)
                Spacer()
                VStack(spacing: 4) {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.label))
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
        .clipShape(Rectangle())
        .shadow(color: Color(UIColor.label), radius: 1)
    }
}
```

This gives the look you want, and allows you to trigger the selection by tapping anywhere on the `CustomPickerView`.